# Batch file with powershell command changing font style

Tags: powershell, batch-file, encoding, cmd, utf-8

I have a batch file which should display umlaute. I have found out, that you have to use `chcp 65001` and therefore I need to use the font style `Lucida Console` in the console. This works fine.

When using `chcp 1252` umlaute are not displayed correctly, the text is read from a csv file with a UTF-8 encoding.

But now I need to run powershell commands from this bat file. These commands change the font style because of this the cmd closes when it is trying to display umlaute. Is there any workaround to fix this?

Below is the most important part of my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
chcp 65001

rem ...

set InputFile=C:\Users\...\Documents\file.csv    

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('powershell -Command [DateTime]::Today.AddDays^(-2^).ToString^(\"dd.MM.yyyy\"^)') do (
    rem ...
)

rem ...

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type "%InputFile%"') do (
    rem ...
    for %%g in (%%i) do (
        rem ...
        set /A outyear=tyear-year
        set out[!index!]=!data[1]! !data[2]! !data[3]! !outyear! 
        set /A index=!index!+1 
    )
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set out[') do echo %%s
```

Following is a short snippet of the CSV file for testing purpose:

```
Test;Musterman;Max;Test;21.01.1991
Test;Musterman2;Max2aöüäß;Test;22.01.1993
Test;Musterman3;Mülleraöüäß;Test;23.01.1989
```

I already tried the following [Why does running PowerShell change my console font?](https://superuser.com/questions/706562/why-does-running-powershell-change-my-console-font) but it did not work.

**Note** I am also working on **Windows 7**, maybe this is also a reason why it does not work.

Comment: Not able to test this as my windows 10 machine does not reproduce your issue. have you tried `start /b powershell` instead by any chance? alternatively, you can run the powershell loop in a nother batch file, and send back the value to this batch file, but again I won't be able to test it as I do not get the same issues.

Comment: I am working on Windows 7, will try your suggested method.

Comment: Can not reproduce. There are not even any umlauts in your example. I ran your script and worked just fine, did not crash at all. I am not even sure why it should.

Comment: @marsze I read text from a csv file with umlaute which are then displayed in the cmd, this does not work.

Comment: @Meister96Fels The code example you posted does no CSV parsing or displaying of umlauts whatsoever, so how are we supposed to know what your problem is?

Comment: @marsze Added now some code for the parsing of the CSV file, but I am not sure what do post since the hole file is around 300 lines and I wanted only to post the most important parts.

Comment: @Meister96Fels An extract of the CSV would have been reasonable, or any other kind of output with umlauts to ***reproduce*** the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem with the suggested method of @GerhardBarnard.

I now start the batch file via a second file, this file runs the powershell commands and then calls the other batch file with the parameters. Which looks like this:

```
@echo off

rem ...

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('powershell -Command [DateTime]::Today.AddDays^(1^).ToString^(\"dd.MM.yyyy\"^)') do (
    rem ...
)

rem ...

call File.bat %param1% %param2% %param3% %param4%
```

In the second file I now parse CSV file and since the powershell commands are run in a different batch file the font style is not changed. Therefore it can display all umlaute without any problems.